# Capturing IR Data using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, hid, infrared

Just found an old IR reciever (Microsoft eHome Infared Transceiver) and i'm trying to write an application that can use data it captures...

Any examples or jumping off points for this are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719703/is-it-possible-to-host-an-aspx-web-page-in-a-stand-alone-application-outside-of/719719#719719) it's a USB [HID device](http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm). As such, you should be able to use Win32 API to talk to it - [similar](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2006/10/31/912422.aspx) to other USB HID devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Microsoft eHome Infared Transceiver is a Human Interface Device (HID), so I'd start with [The HID Page](http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm).

This has a VB.NET sample on it.